# Add character automatically in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to automatically put a "0" if character less then 6 letters in my EditText until reach maxlength. I want the user writes : 123 and it appears 123000 in the EditText.

But I don't know how to do this and if it is possible.
Can you help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adds zero's to the edittext until it has a length of six.

```
void addZero(Edittext mEdittext){
    if(mEdittext.getText().length < 6){
        while(mEdittext.getText().length < 6){
            mEdittext.setText(mEdittext.getText() + "0");
        }
    }
}
```

Call it with

```
addZero(myEditTextObject);
```

Use a TextWatcher if you need live appending.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use a TextWatcher.  Put a TextWatcher on the EditText, and check what the length of the text is in afterTextChanged.  If the length is less than 6, append 0s to it to pad to 6.